# ajuda com Qlocale e formato moeda brasil

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt-4

em c++ eu costumava converter um valor inteiro para o formato de moeda brasileiro da seguinte maneira:

```
QLocale loc = QLocale::system();
QLocale brasil(QLocale::Portuguese);
loc.setNumberOptions(brasil.numberOptions());
QLocale::setDefault(loc);

cout << brasil.toString(orcamentoDisponivel * 0.01, 'f', 2).toStdString();
```

em PyQt, fiz isto:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore
orcamentoDisponivel = 225710000
loc = QtCore.QLocale.system().name()
lang = QtCore.QLocale(loc) # ou substituir loc por 'pt_BR' 
print lang.toString(int(orcamentoDisponivel * 0.01))
```

O problema é que enquanto em c++ eu tinha como saída, por exemplo: 2.257.100,00 (valor correto para meu caso)

em python eu tenho como saída: 225.710.000

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver isto?
Obrigado!

Comment: Verifique se self.orcamentoDisponivel é float ou int

Comment: Fica difícil de afirmar com certeza se o problema é esse (que tal vc produzir um [mcve] que reproduza o erro, hein?), mas a classe `QLocale` tem [várias sobrecargas diferentes do método `toString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#toString). Algumas aceitam valores inteiros. Vc tem certeza que o seu valor em `self.orcamentoDisponivel` está representado como um valor real? De qualquer forma, deve funcionar se vc fizer: `lang.toString(float(self.orcamentoDisponivel))`.

Comment: P.S.: Note também que na sua implementação em C++ você multiplica o valor por 0.01 (o que é equivalente a dividir por 100). E você não faz essa multiplicação no Python. O problema pode ter relação com isso aí também.

Comment: self.orcamentoDisponivel = integer.

Comment: Desculpa, agora tem o exemplo mínimo.

Comment: Bom, o número `225710000` **é bem diferente** do número `2257100`. Eu repito: parece que você somente se esqueceu de dividir por 100, tal como faz lá no C++. Experimente trocar a chamada `print lang.toString(orcamentoDisponivel)` por `print lang.toString(int(orcamentoDisponivel * 0.01))`.

Comment: Realmente  faltava dividir (obrigado), mas ainda não exibe as duas casas após a virgula. ex: orcamentoDisponivel = 225710035. o output seria: 2.257.100.

Comment: Claro que não. Inteiros não têm casas após a vírgula. :) Mas você pode formatar como `float` da mesma forma como faz em C++. Falta um pouco de atenção, hein? É só usar o mesmo código. (Observe que a interface de `QLocale` em ambas as linguagens é *exatamente a mesma*.)

Comment: E aí luiz, beleza? valeu por suas contribuições, já resolvi o problema. Uma sugestão para você: você pode ajudar as pessoas sem precisar ser ranzinza. Abraço e obrigado novemante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido:

```
#https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') 
print locale.format('%.2f', (value * 0.01), True)
```

ou

```
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917083/qlocale-and-brazil-currency-format    
from PyQt4 import QtCore
value = 225710000
lang = QtCore.QLocale('pt_BR')
print lang.toString(value * 0.01, 'f', 2)
```